# Need to round in multiples of 0.25

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I need to round the currency amount in 0.25, 0.50, 0.75 and if greater than 0.75, it must round to the next integer.

How to do it?

Example need to round:

- 25.91 to 26,
- 25.21 to 25.25
- 25.44 to 25.50

and so on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to round to the next highest quarter, you can use [`math.ceil()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html).

```
>>> import math
>>> def quarter(x):
...     return math.ceil(x*4)/4
...
>>> quarter(25.91)
26.0
>>> quarter(25.21)
25.25
>>> quarter(25.44)
25.5
```

If you want to round to the closest quarter instead of the next highest, just replace `math.ceil` with `round`:

```
>>> def nearest_quarter(x):
...     return round(x*4)/4
...
>>> nearest_quarter(4.51)
4.5
```